# Android: Drawer effect while opening an Activity

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

There are two screens with different layout. I put an image below.[image]

[image]

I want to display Actiivty1 with full screen and Activity2 with 20% of the screen. And while tap on Activity2, screen should open with drawer functionality.
I refer many examples of Sliding drawer. But i could not able to find solution.

If anybody have idea, please let me know.. It would be very helpful..

Thank you

Comment: What went wrong when trying out the examples?

Comment: i cannot able to do slide drawer type of effect. And how to open 20% part of other activity to HomeScreen?

Comment: I'm not sure you should think of it as 20% of an activity. It's more like a menu-bar that can open a new activity, right? (or possibly bundle it all into one activity with some fragments/transitions etc. I don't know what I'm talking about)

Comment: Its not a menu-bar, its part of other activity. that's why I right there 20% screen part of activity2. While closing Activity2, it should keep open 20% part of Activity2 to HomeScreen.

Comment: I'm not sure you accomplish that using separate activities.

Comment: could you please give some idea, how to do this.. please